# When does SQL Server CTE statement execute

Tags: sql, view, common-table-expression

This may be a bit of a dumb question but I just wanted to check exactly when a `WITH` statement fires. This is probably best described via an example. We have the view at the bottom.

The view extracts the required information from the XML Nodes to make it easier to display on reports, screens etc... We will only ever call this view passing in a Date range or a TableName.

My question is, when this view is called as ...

```
select * 
from [Core].[vw_DBAudit] 
where TableName = 'CorporateActions'
```

will the `WITH` statement only run for records with `TableName = 'CorporateActions'` or will it run for ALL records. I.e. will it strip out the XML nodes for ALL records in the table, or only for ones where the `tablename = 'CorporateActions'`? My concern is that it's doing more work than it needs to. If it'll run for all records then I'll remove the `WITH` statement and just just code it as a select. This code is written by someone else so I want to be sure before I go back to them.

```
CREATE VIEW [Core].[vw_DBAudit]
AS
WITH AuditTable
AS
(
SELECT
     r.Actions
    ,r.CreatedBy
    ,r.WhenCreated
    ,r.WhenModified
    ,r.TableName
    ,r.EntityKey
    ,r.UserId
    ,r.RevisionStamp
    ,(SELECT u.UserName FROM aspnet_Users u WHERE u.UserId = r.UserId) AS UserName  
    ,a.changeddata.value('Property[1]', 'varchar(100)')  AS Property
    ,a.changeddata.value('OldValue[1]', 'varchar(100)')  AS OldValue
    ,a.changeddata.value('NewValue[1]', 'varchar(100)')  AS NewValue
    ,a.changeddata.value('(OldValue/@xsi:type)[1]','varchar(30)')  AS OldValueDataType
    ,a.changeddata.value('(NewValue/@xsi:type)[1]','varchar(30)')  AS NewValueDataType  

FROM 
    Core.DBAudit r
    cross apply r.[ChangedColumns].nodes('/ArrayOfModifiedProperty/ModifiedProperty') as a(changeddata)
)

SELECT 
     r.*
    ,CASE WHEN  r.OldValueDataType = 'xsd:dateTime' THEN        
           CONVERT(DATETIME, substring(r.OldValue,1,19)) 
     ELSE
       null 
     END  as 'OldDateValue'      
    ,CASE WHEN  r.NewValueDataType = 'xsd:dateTime'  THEN         
           CONVERT(DATETIME, substring(r.NewValue,1,19)) 
     ELSE
        null
     END  as 'NewDateValue'   
 FROM  AuditTable r
```

Comment: You can check that by having a look at the execution plan. It should be obvious if the filter on `TableName` is done before the shredding of the XML. My *guess* would be that it is filtered before but you have to check the plan to make sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before the query analyzer determines a query plan, it expands both views and a CTEs.  Writing a query with a CTE does not affect how the query will be run.